# Is policy version in BRE Resolver in Itinerary really needed using Biztalk ESB toolkit?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Like the title says, must I really specify policy version when using a BRE resolver?

I thought that part of the idea with using BRE was that I wouldn't have to alter my deployed solution(including the itinerary) if I decide to change a policy in BRE (which leads to a new policy version).

Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to but this allows for flexibility if you have several deployed/published policies you can then specify which to use.  In your case you just need to make sure that you only ever have one version available for the resolver to use.

Comment: Ok, but how do I achieve this? When selecting a policy in visual studio I'm forced to choose a version

Comment: Selecting a policy where? In the pipeline component?

Comment: No, in my Itinerary, more specific the messagingextender component, just noticed that you can erase the version number in visual studio properties window after you've selected the version specific policy